# Laplace transform in probability question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, laplace-transform

A component has a failure rate of $\lambda$ (i.e. the probability of failure in period ∆t is λ∆t).

Show that the probability that the component will have failed by time t is $F(t) = 1 − e^{−\lambda t}$

Derive the mean and variance of the time to failure.

---

I am stuck in the  last part of the question where we need to find the variance. I know that

$$\mathbb E(t^2)=\int_0^\infty t^2\cdot  \lambda  e^{−\lambda t} \,dt $$

How do I convert the above integral into Laplace so that it is easy to solve?

The answer for the variance is $\frac1{\lambda^2}$.

Comment: I think what you're alluding to is the idea of computing the moment generating function $E[e^{tX}]=\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{tx} e^{-\lambda x} dx$. You could do that. A different way to do it is to just work with the integral you wrote directly using integration by parts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ian. I'm not sure how to solve that integral and thought that maybe converting it into Laplace would be easier but I am stuck in that as well. So I guess my key question is how to solve that integral using Laplace Transform.

Comment: I mean what I said is the Laplace transform of the density. This is also called the moment generating function because $E[X^n]=\left. \frac{d^n}{dt^n} E[e^{tX}] \right |_{t=0}$, provided the right side makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! But how exactly do we take the Laplace Transform of the density? I'm still not sure sorry :(

Comment: You just compute the integral I wrote...it should be easy to do.